# Runtime.getruntime().exec not working properly with gedit on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, runtime, gedit

I need to open a txt file from a location on Ubuntu (e.x. /usr/local/share/SomeFolder/Readme.txt) through my java code.

I've used Runtime.getRuntime.exec(String) and Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args) with gedit but it opens a new tab alongside the Readme.txt file.

The code is as below

```
String x="gedit /usr/local/share/SomeFolder/Readme.txt";
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(x);

<OR>

String[] args={"gedit","/usr/local/share/SomeFolder/Readme.txt"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args)
```

I've also tried using ProcessBuilder but it behaves the same way. Also i've explored different options of gedit but still no luck.

When I run "gedit /usr/local/share/SomeFolder/Readme.txt" from terminal it opens only one instance and that of the Readme.txt file.

Maybe gedit is programmed to behave this way or I am doing something wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

> I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,64 Bit with Eclipse Juno SR2 (JDK 1.7u51)

Thanks !

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder` instead

Comment: I've used that as well.

Comment: share the code that uses `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: String args[]={"gedit","/usr/local/share/SomeFolder/Readme.txt"};
Process pb=new ProcessBuilder(args).start();

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Are you reading the `Process`s output?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't get any error as such, just opens two windows.

Comment: This is very likely a behaviour of gedit that you can only work around. Maybe something like `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("bash -c gedit /usr/local/share/SomeFolder/Readme.txt");` can help.

Comment: @ammoQ I just tried that, but now it opens an empty document only not the Readme.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i just tested using ProcessBuilder

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("gedit", "/home/honey/filename.json");
    pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);

    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();

    //This will print console logs of your process
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = p.getInputStream();
        int in = -1;

        while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) in);
        }

    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But this too opens a new document window alongside the existing one. No console logs printed. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,64 Bit with Eclipse Juno SR2 (JDK 1.7u51)

Comment: May be i misunderstood, So what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to prevent launching of another instance of a document when I launch a txt file using gedit. When i launch it using process builder/runtime.getRuntime it opens an additional window. Please try it out and see it would open another instance.

Comment: I am working on CentOS, see this result with same code [link](http://imgur.com/xHqOCYR) . I tried to change the name of file.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and can't test it on the environment you have. If you get a chance please test it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah You are right, it always open a new empty document in ubuntu. I tested here. Its  unpredictable :( , Sorry bad luck for you.